# Custom UICollectionViewCell (tableview inside collectionviewcell)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, calendar, uicollectionviewcell

I am new at this and I heard a lot the term “custom Collectionviewcell” when looking how to make a calendar in which squares have a list of events (like google calendar), because I read I could use a custom collectionviewcell to have a tableview inside each collectionviewcell.
The thing is that I looked for it and I still don’t know what it is or how to implement it. Anyone does?
Thanks, Mateo.

Comment: If you are new as you said to iOS, you may have a hard time building and implementing a component like a calendar, you may want to look up cocoapods and find a library that helps you with that, since the logic embedded in a calendar can be quite difficult when you consider leap years, I'd personally recommend this library https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar

Comment: But isn’t there an easier way with tableviews inside collectionviewcells?

Comment: Easier is subjective here, if you are new to this, you can try start by learning and how to make a simple custom cell, then you can jump to nest a component like a tableView inside a collectionViewCell, either with the help of the Interface Builder or by code, but I was assuming you wanted to go faster with whatever you're developing, hence I recommended the libraries option.

Comment: The thing is that I don’t want to install anything in my computer. Do you know about a video or something to learn how to make a custom cell? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want looks like this. But I would recommend looking at tutorials for UICollectionView and UITableView, and slowly working your way up to what you want to implement. Hopefully you can grasp the concept of this. But in theory this is how you implement a tableview inside a uicollectionviewCell.

**First a class**

```
    class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewCOntroller, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

        private let collectionViewCellIdentifier = "myCell"            

        override func viewDidLoad() {
             super.viewDidLoad()


        }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell

    return cell
}
```

**Then you want you make another Class**

```
    class YourCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

     lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView()
    tv.delegate = self
    tv.dataSource = self
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return tv
     }()

    }


      override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant:0 ),
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant:0),
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
     }

  }
```

**and then a Extension of YOurCustumCell:**

```
    extension ReceivedCell: UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1 

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell // Or perhaps a custom tableview cell class swell


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Great, but do I need to connect something in the storyboard with this code.

Comment: If you choose to use storyboard yes. but remember this was more for guidance, dummy code, but this is the template, but I think things will make more sense would you follow some simple tutorials on the subject.